# UIBarButtonSystemItemSave width unequal to UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have seven `UIBarButtonItem`s in a `UIToolbar`.

1. UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
2. UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
3. UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
4. UIBarButton with custom text
5. UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
6. UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
7. UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace

Everything is laying out as I would normally expect it to except for the `UIBarButtonSystemItemSave` item. It has an extra space next to it.

I added borders to each subview inside of the toolbar to try to figure out what was happening but still couldn't quite figure it out.

[image: 1 point borders around every subview in the toolbar]

Maybe there was something happening with the order of the buttons so I switched the items around in order, but still couldn't figure it out.

[image: With the Other button on the right the alignment is just fine...except for the Save button in the middle]

Just in case it was something about the way I created the button, I changed the init option to `UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel` for both Save and Cancel.

[image: Cancel aligns just fine. Save is still a problem]

Here's the code that I've been using.

```
- (UIToolbar *)headerToolbar {
    if (!_headerToolbar) {
        _headerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.headerToolbarFrame];
        _headerToolbar.barTintColor = [[OVThemeManager shared] blueColor];
        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionLeftToRight) {
            _headerToolbar.items = @[[self fixedSpace:buttonBufferWidth],
                                     self.cancelButton,
                                     self.flexibleSpace,
                                     self.titleButton,
                                     self.flexibleSpace,
                                     self.saveButton,
                                     [self fixedSpace:buttonBufferWidth]];
        } else {
            _headerToolbar.items = @[[self fixedSpace:buttonBufferWidth],
                                     self.saveButton,
                                     self.flexibleSpace,
                                     self.titleButton,
                                     self.flexibleSpace,
                                     self.cancelButton,
                                     [self fixedSpace:buttonBufferWidth]];
        }

        [self borderSubviews:self.headerToolbar];
    }

    return _headerToolbar;
}

- (void)borderSubviews:(UIView *)superview {
    superview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    superview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.001f *(float)(arc4random()%1000)
                                                  green:0.001f *(float)(arc4random()%1000)
                                                   blue:0.001f *(float)(arc4random()%1000)
                                                  alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    for (UIView *subview in superview.subviews) {
        [self borderSubviews:subview];
    }
}

- (CGRect)headerToolbarFrame {
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

    frame.size.height = headerToolbarHeight;

    return frame;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)saveButton {
    if (!_saveButton) {
        _saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(saveButtonTouched:)];
        _saveButton.tintColor = [[OVThemeManager shared] blueColor];
    }

    return _saveButton;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)cancelButton {
    if (!_cancelButton) {
        _cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(cancelButtonTouched:)];
        _cancelButton.tintColor = [[OVThemeManager shared] blueColor];
    }

    return _cancelButton;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)titleButton {
    if (!_titleButton) {
        _titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Other button".localized
                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                       target:nil
                                                       action:nil];
        _titleButton.tintColor = [[OVThemeManager shared] blueColor];
    }

    return _titleButton;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)flexibleSpace {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                         target:nil
                                                         action:nil];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)fixedSpace:(CGFloat)width {
    UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                                                                target:nil
                                                                                action:nil];
    fixedSpace.width = width;
    return fixedSpace;
}
```